# Instantiating a 2d List that stores ArrayList with integer lists in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
class Solution {
    public int longestIncreasingPath(int[][] matrix) {
        List<ArrayList<Integer>>[][] dp = new List[matrix.length][matrix[0].length];
        for (int i = matrix.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = matrix[0].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                dp[i][j] = new ArrayList<>();
                if (j - 1 >= 0 && matrix[i][j-1] < matrix[i][j]) {
                    int[] pair = new int[2];
                    pair[0] = i;
                    pair[1] = j - 1;
                    dp[i][j].add(pair);
                }
                if (j + 1 < matrix[0].length && matrix[i][j+1] < matrix[i][j]) {
                    int[] pair = new int[2];
                    pair[0] = i;
                    pair[1] = j + 1;
                    dp[i][j].add(pair);
                }
                if (i - 1 >= 0 && matrix[i-1][j] < matrix[i][j]) {
                    int[] pair = new int[2];
                    pair[0] = i - 1;
                    pair[1] = j;
                    dp[i][j].add(pair);
                }
                if (i + 1 < matrix.length && matrix[i+1][j] < matrix[i][j]) {
                    int[] pair = new int[2];
                    pair[0] = i + 1;
                    pair[1] = j;
                    dp[i][j].add(pair);
                }
            }
        }

        int[][] longest = new int[matrix.length][matrix[0].length];

        HashSet<List<Integer>> visited = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = matrix.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = matrix[0].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                longest[i][j] = 0;
                ArrayList<Integer> element = dp[i][j];
                dfs(visited, element, i, j, longest, dp);
            }
        }

        int length = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++) {
                if (longest[i][j] > length) {
                    length = longest[i][j];
                }
            }
        }

        return length;

    }

    public void dfs(HashSet<List<Integer>> visited, ArrayList<Integer> neighbors, int x, int y, int[][] longest, List<ArrayList<Integer>>[][] dp) {
        for (int i = 0; i < neighbors.size(); i++) {
            neighbor = neighbors[i];
            n_x = neighbor[0];
            n_y = neighbor[1];
            neighbor_list = dp[n_x][n_y];
            if (!visited.contains(neighbors[i])) {
                dfs(visited, neighbor_list, n_x, n_y, longest, dp);
            }
            if (longest[n_x][n_y] > longest[x][y]) {
                longest[x][y] = longest[n_x][n_y] + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have written the above code. I'm receiving an error for the line(s) dp[i][j].add(pair)

error: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to ArrayList
dp[i][j].add(pair);.

I'm uncertain why I'm receiving that error. I want to instantiate a 2D List where each entry stores an ArrayList of Integer Lists where each list has length 2. I'm unsure about what I'm doing incorrectly. I believe that I correctly initially instantiated a list of ArrayLists (dp); then, for each entry in dp, I instantiated an ArrayList for which I append the list(s) to. What am I doing that's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The constructor `List<ArrayList<Integer>>[][] dp = new List[matrix.length][matrix[0].length];` is incorrect. That creates a 2D array of Lists of ArrayLists of Integers. I believe you are trying to achieve `ArrayList[][] dp = new ArrayList[matrix.length][matrix[0].length];`? This will remove the error. If I understand your question correctly, this should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

use `dp[i][j].add(new ArrayList<>(List.of(pair)));` it will create a new ArrayList<int[]> and adding it to the 2D ArrayList dp[i][j]. This is done to ensure that each element in the dp array is an independent ArrayList.